# Error JSON object SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unterminated string withSpring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

Help me Please. 
JSON object SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unterminated string

JAVA code

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "getMessage.htm")
public @ResponseBody String getStatusServer(ModelMap model, HttpSession session,@RequestParam("key") String key)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    BufferData bufferData = DataMap.dataMap.get(key);
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    content.append("{\"status\":").append(bufferData.getStatus()).append(",").append("  \"messages\": \"").append(bufferData.getMess()).append("\"}");
    System.out.println(content.toString());

    return content.toString();
}
```

JQuery code

```
    function getMessage() {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "<c:url value="/"/>" + "getMessage.htm",
        data : 'key=' + 'job1',
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("test");
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error : function(data, status, er) {
            alert("error: " + data + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
        }

    });
}
```

Error code

```
    SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unterminated string
```

Help me Please. 
and json output

```
{"status":1, "messages":"Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic x86_64) * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/ System information as of Fri Jun 21 17:13:41 ICT 2013 System load: 0.08 Processes: 265 Usage of /: 13.9% of 38.02GB Users logged in: 2 Memory usage: 51% IP address for eth0: 10.216.92.20 Swap usage: 31% => There are 2 zombie processes. Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/ Last login: Fri Jun 21 16:30:33 2013 from wachirawat.local vos1@icenaja:~$ hostname icenaja vos1@icenaja:~$ pwd /home/vos1 vos1@icenaja:~$ exit logout "}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you use some library (such as Jackson) to build your JSON responses. http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like valid json, try the below to see if it then will send.

```
data = {
            "key": "job1"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what do you want to do with line.
`url : "<c:url value="/"/>" + "getMessage.htm",`

If this is nexted string value, try this single codes instead of double.

```
url : "<c:url value='/'/>" + "getMessage.htm"
```

Comment: `c:url` will get to the base location of the webapp so you don't have to do `../` each time you get further down the url path.  It gets rendered by the JSP.